# Android Studio - Emulator displaying Brown Header and Can't Remove (Pepper)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pepper

[Header Image on Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwPDM.png)

Running my code in Android Studio displays a large brown header on the tablet and messes up the formatting of the actual Android Manifest design that I have created for that specific tablet size
(1280 x 800).

This is in regards to developing for the Pepper robot.
The image is attached above.

Any help would be appreciated!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This header is called the speech bar, and it is included in `RobotActivity`, to provide the user with feedback on Pepper's speech recognition and synthesis.
You can [configure it](https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch2_principles/conversation_feedbacks.html?highlight=speechbar#speechbar-strategies) to change its appearance and position.

My preferred parameters are `IMMERSIVE` and `TOP`

```java
class MyActivity : RobotActivity(), RobotLifecycleCallbacks {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setSpeechBarDisplayStrategy(SpeechBarDisplayStrategy.IMMERSIVE)
        setSpeechBarDisplayPosition(SpeechBarDisplayPosition.TOP)
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity)

        QiSDK.register(this, this)
    }
}
```